# Two divs to display on image mouseover

Tags: css, html, mouseover

---

> finally figured out the result , used both js and css together to work,
>   thanks guys :)
>   **[FINAL JSFIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/GKa9p/1/)**
>
> **find codes below**
>
> ---

i have made an example with using other codes, to display `'info <DIV>'` to show up when mouseover on image, but i m having problem when i try to show `"caption <DIV>"` over the image. i have tried to add codes in the css but anything i do stops `"info <DIV>"` to show up :(

can some one please look into this set of code :[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gygHg/32)

and if the `"info <DIV>"` can be displayed in a separate `<div>` it would be great help.
thanks
regards.

**code html**

```
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh-cl/256/Symbols-Critical-icon.png" class="team"/>

<div class="info">"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR></div>

<div class="caption">SYMBOL</div> 

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh-cl/256/Symbols-Favourite-1-icon.png" alt="" class="team"/>

<div class="info">and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR></div>

<div class="caption">STAR</div>
​
```

**CSS code**

```
.team , .info{
 background: #151515;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px; 

}
.info{

    background:white;
    height: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    display:none;
position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}


.team:hover + .info {

   display:block; }


.team {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

   .team:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      }​
```

Comment: Why don't you give us what you have so far?

Comment: @salih0vicX: he has. In the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Oh sorry; missed it somehow .. Thanks!

Comment: A JSFiddle is great, but I think it would be preferred to add the relevant code to the question as well. That way, if the [link rots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) the question will still be useful to future visitors.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put codes here.

Comment: i just learnt some of the html code last week and css is just hit and try for me at this moment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the caption class in the css and styled the caption.
In your code the caption would stay under the image. Then i set the `position:relative` and set the position of 20px from the bottom. I gave it a `background-color:red` in order to let you see where it is located. I also gave the caption a width of 150px as the width of the images. You used the classes `team`, `info` and `caption`. In order to target the mouseover function separetely in every image i created 2 different kind of classes for every image, so: `team1`, `team2`, `info1`, `info2`, `caption1`, `caption2`. If you use want to use 3 images on your webpage you'll have to add `team3`, `info3`, `caption3` and so on, in your html, css and jquery function. (You can just copy and paste and rename). i added a parent div with id `image` that wraps every image and gives relative positioning. You can edit the code as you want.

Here is the edited HTML:

```
<div id="image">
 <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh-cl/256/Symbols-  Critical-icon.png" class="team1"/>

<div class="info1">"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"    <BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"    <BR>"this is a symbol"<BR></div>

<div class="caption1">SYMBOL</div> 
</div>
<div id="image">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh-cl/256/Symbols-    Favourite-1-icon.png" alt="" class="team2"/>

<div class="info2">and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a    star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR></div>

<div class="caption2">STAR</div>
</div>​
```

​

Here's the edited CSS:

```
.team1 {
 background: #151515;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

}

.info1{
background: white;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 visibility:hidden;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
}

.team2{
 background: #151515;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;    

}

.info2 {
background: white;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 visibility:hidden;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
}

.team1:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
}

.team2:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
}

.caption1  {
position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    width:150px;
    bottom:20px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.caption2  {
position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    width:150px;
    bottom:20px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#image {
position:relative;
}
```

​

Then i added some jquery functions that you can put in the body of your html page after the other html code:

```
$(".team1").mouseout(function () {
    $(".caption1").css("visibility","hidden");
 $(".info1").css("visibility","hidden");   

  });


$(".team1").mouseover(function () {
    $(".caption1").css("visibility","visible");
$(".info1").css("visibility","visible");
});

$(".team2").mouseout(function () {
    $(".caption2").css("visibility","hidden");
$(".info2").css("visibility","hidden");
  });


$(".team2").mouseover(function () {
    $(".caption2").css("visibility","visible");
$(".info2").css("visibility","visible");
  });
```

​In order to use the jquery functions you have to include the jquery library in your page by inserting: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` in the head of your HTML page, like this:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsQ5h/8/)

Comment: thanks, but i want to display the caption on the image itself on mouseover. eveytime i try to do that the info box stops working.

Comment: Yes you are right. I read it more carefully now. I'll edit the code for you.

Comment: I edited the code and posted a new jsfiddle. Take a look. It should be what you want. @case13

Comment: PERFECT!!! thanks fabio. :D ok although it all i wanted but is it possible to display the info box within a different div(lets say "Display")

Comment: so if need to add new images i have to add new codes in javascript and css :O ? can it be controlled by single entry?

Comment: Hmm..now the info1 and info2 are displayed in the same absolute position that is top:10px and right:10px . Would you like to display the info related to the second image on the right of the second image? @case13

Comment: yes currently you would have to add new code in javascript and css. (just copy and paste and rename though, not difficult). I'm thinking of a single entry function but it's more complicated.I have to think. @case13

Comment: i improved the code. Now the info box is displayed on the right of each image aligned horizontally with it. Check the new code and jsfiddle. If you are satisfied, please vote for my answer, i put efforts in helping you :) @case13

Answer (score 1):

Its unbelievable what CSS is capable of doing - but don't abuse it too much. There has been some really fancy widgets and templates I have seen done entirely in CSS (which is great) but I would suggest to be careful when you "hack" CSS vs. using javascript. IMHO this is a css hack:

```
.team:hover + .info {
  display:block;
}
```

It is OK to use CSS to change the style/display of an element NESTED within that element for instance:

```
<div>
  <a class="close" href="#">Close me</a>
</div>
```

When you hover over `<div` then `a.close` should show up (display: block;).

In your specific case - you are using css to change a NON-NESTED element's display. Using javascript is recommended instead of a css hack because if you ever (and most likely you will) want to enable a user to move their mouse away from the picture and hover over the caption div and highlight text, click on link... etc. you will HAVE to use javascript. CSS is limited in its capabilities and its complexity greatly increases when you use transcend beyond its intended purposes.

As such, I recommend javascript (w/ jquery or other library).

Comment: thanks, i guess u r right css sometimes can do wonder and in some cases holds you back..

Answer (score 0):

**Final code**

html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>



  <style type='text/css'>

      .team img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

}
.team .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);

}

.team .caption a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
  </style>




<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.team').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(100);
});

$('.team').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(100);
});
});//]]>  

</script>
      <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.team').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.info').fadeIn(100);
});

$('.team').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.info').fadeOut(100);
});
});//]]>  

</script>

<div class="team">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh-cl/256/Symbols-Critical-icon.png" >

<div class="caption">SYMBOL</div>

<div class="info">"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR>"this is a symbol"<BR></div></div>

<div class="team">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tpdkdesign.net/refresh-cl/256/Symbols-Favourite-1-icon.png">

<div class="caption">STAR</div>

<div class="info">and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR>and this is a star<BR></div></div>

</body>​
```

css

```
.team {
 background: #151515;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px; 
    position: relative;

}
.info{
    background:white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
position:fixed;
    float:right;
    top: 0px;
    left: 70% ;
    z-index: 99;
}
```